# Is every class that does not add sets necessarily added by forcing? 

Tags: set-theory, forcing, lo.logic

We know there are many situations in which we can force over a model $M$ of GBC to add a class $G$ without adding any sets.  That is, the extension $M[G]$ satisfies GBC and has the same sets as $M$.  This technique is used, for example, in the proof that GBC is a conservative extension of ZFC, by forcing to add a universal choice function to a model of ZFC.

I'd like to know whether every class that can be 'safely' added to a model (preserving GBC and adding no sets) arises through forcing:

> If $M$ is a model of GBC and $G$ is a class (that is, a subcollection of the sets of $M$, not a class member of $M$) such that $M[G]$ satisfies GBC and has the same sets as $M$, then is $G$ necessarily generic for some partial order $P \in M$?

I feel 'morally certain' that the answer must be no.  Certainly the analogous question about sets, 'Can every set be added by forcing?' has a negative answer - we cannot, for example, force over $L$ to add a measure to a cardinal $\kappa$ (or to add $0^\\#$, or any other set that might increase the consistency strength).  However, I don't see how to adapt this kind of argument to classes, if we are not allowed to add sets.  I'd love to see a counterexample (a proof of a positive answer would also be welcome!).

Comment: A $\Pi^1_1$-singleton class could not be added by forcing. I haven't worked out how to make this work, but here is the plan... Find a formula $\forall Z \phi(X,Z)$ where $\phi$ only has set quantifiers but $Z$ ranges over classes which provably has at most one solution $X$ but no solution definable by comprehension using only set quantifiers. The unique solution cannot be added by forcing over the model of NBG where all classes are defined by comprehension using only quantification over sets.

Comment: @Jonas: I deleted my answer since it did not take your requirement that $G$ not be a member of the GB-model. On the other hand, I have an argument that shows your hunch is right if we also insist that the notion of forcing $P$ be Ord-closed in the sense of $M$; and I will try to see if this condition can be removed.

Comment: François, do you expect that we should be able to add a $\Pi^1_1$ singleton class over any model of ZFC? My answer seems to illustrate your plan, for models that admit a satisfaction class, since "being a satisfaction class" is even first-order expressible in the language with a predicate for the class. 

Comment: I expected that this would be possible but Ali pointed out that it might not be. Satisfaction classes are examples of $\Pi^1_1$ singletons but I wanted to avoid these since they can add new sets. It would be interesting to know which models have $\Pi^1_1$ singletons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a fantastic question, Jonas! I've spent hours with it now, going back and forth  several times about which way it might go.

But finally, I've got a negative answer, at least for some models $M$. My idea is
that some models of ZFC admit what are called *satisfaction
classes*, but these can never be added by class forcing.

For any transitive model $M$ of ZFC, let $S$ be the set of pairs
$\langle{}^\ulcorner\varphi{}^\urcorner,a\rangle$, for which
$\varphi[a]$ holds in $M$. This class $S$ is the (unique) class of
pairs $\langle n,a\rangle$ satisfying the Tarskian inductive
definition of truth. Further, we may sometimes add $S$ as a class
to $M$ and still have GBC in $(M,S)$. This is true, for example,
when $M=V_\kappa$ for an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$; but also
it is true for many other models.

So let us suppose that $M$ admits such a unique satisfaction
class.

Can $S$ be added by class forcing over $M$ without adding sets? If
we regard $M$ as a GB model by endowing it with only its definable
classes, then the answer is no.

To see this, suppose that $S$ was added in the class forcing
extension $M[H]$, where $H\subset\mathbb{P}$ is $M$-generic for
the class forcing $\mathbb{P}$, which adds no sets. So
$S=\dot{A}_H$ for some class $\mathbb{P}$-name $\dot{A}$, and in
particular, both $\dot{A}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ are definable in $M$.

Now, the key step is that although truth itself is not definable,
by Tarski's theorem, the property of $S$ that it satisfies the
inductive definition of truth has complexity merely $\Delta_1(S)$.
Thus, one of the assertions about $S$ that is true in $M[H]$ is
that it satisfies the Tarskian definition of truth. Thus, there
must be a condition forcing that $\dot{A}$ is a satisfaction
class, obeying Tarski's inductive definition.

But since the satisfaction class of $M$ is unique, this means
that there is no choice for the generic filter whether or not to
place a pair into or out of $\dot{A}$. Thus, inside $M$ by simply
looking at which pairs can be added at all to the class named by
$\dot{A}$, we can define $S$ in $M$. But this contradicts Tarski's
theorem on the non-definability of truth. QED

Let me argue next that we don't actually need the satisfaction class to be unique, and
the same argument will work whenever $M$ admits a satisfaction
class at all, with GBC in $(M,S)$. This can conceivably happen in non-standard models $M$, with non-standard Gödel codes. Nevertheless, the standard
part of the satisfaction class, that is, for standard Gödel
codes, will be unique, and so we can still get that stable part of
the satisfaction class from the name $\dot{A}$---the pairs that
are forced into $\dot{A}$ by every condition. This will still be a
satisfaction predicate, contrary to Tarski's theory of truth, even
if $M$ is not an $\omega$-model and possibly admits several
satisfaction classes.

Finally, let me point out that not every model of ZFC admits a
satisfaction class. For example, if $M$ is 
pointwise definable, as
in our joint paper on [Pointwise definable models of set theory](http://jdh.hamkins.org/pointwisedefinablemodelsofsettheory/), then this property would be revealed by
the satisfaction class, and so we cannot add this class without
revealing to $M$ that it is countable.

Comment: What a great example, Joel! The fact that the satisfaction class is compatible with GBC but is not definable is a very nice combination.  Does existence of a satisfaction class increase the consistency strength of GBC?

Comment: I guess not, because you can make a compactness argument that there must be a ZFC model which admits a satisfaction class with GBC, since for any standard $n$ we can have a $\Sigma_n$-satisfaction class. That is, we can write down the theory of what it means to be a satisfaction class with GBC still holding, and apply compactness. 

Comment: Incidentally, since not every model $M$ admits a satisfaction class with GB, there is still room here for a better answer, which either proves it negatively for all models $M$, or which finds some $M$ to which one cannot add classes except generically.

Comment: Meanwhile, it seems that the compactness argument shows that every model $M$ can be elementarily embedded into a model that admits a satisfaction class (just add the elementary diagram of $M$ to the theory before applying compactness). Thus, the existence of a satisfaction class with GBC is conservative over ZFC, and there can be no obstacle coming just from the theory of $M$. 

Comment: @Joel: Nice answer; the question you pose in your comment is intriguing. Of course, we want to concentrate on *countable* $M$ because there are such things as "rather classless models" of $ZF$, all of whose classes are definable.

Comment: Ah, of course, that is exactly what we need! So this means that one cannot prove that every $M$ admits such a non-forcing extension, since a rather classless model has no extensions at all with the same sets. In particular, there will be $\omega_1$-like models with a positive answer to Jonas's query. (And I believe that with sufficient large cardinals, one can even do this with transitive models of height $\omega_1$.) 

Comment: @Joel: regarding your parenthetical clause: rather classless models $M$ have the property (by definition) that if $X$ is an *amenable* subset of $M$, then $X$ is definable in $M$. Now if $M$ is a well-founded model of $ZF$ of *uncountable* cofinality, then we can use the reflection theorem and an elementary chain argument to show that $Sat_M$ is an amenable subset of $M$. This shows that no well-founded model of $ZF$ can be rather classless. But maybe by weakening the notion of "rather classless" by replacing "amenable" by "satisfies replacement", one can arrange a well-founded such model.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that the class should satisfy GBC, and not merely be amenable, since this is what Jonas is talking about. I have in mind some constructions that I have recently been looking at with Gunter Fuchs, where we do with transitive models (given large cardinals) things that you and Roman Kossak have done with $\omega_1$-like models of arithmetic, and I think our methods works for this rather classless situation also, but I'll have to check it through.